# Wix OAuth2 PHP client example application

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, velo

I am building a PHP website where I want to authenticate users against an external Wix site using OAuth2.  Is there some example PHP code out there for doing it?   I couldn't find any on the Wix site, nor could I find a Wix developers forum where I might ask the question.